# Post JSON to create new contact

Tags: javascript, json, gdata, google-contacts-api, oauth2-playground

I'm trying to create a new contact for an authorised user using javascript and I want to avoid using XML. The playground gives me the option to post JSON but I cannot find the required format anywhere. The current javascript client library doesn't work with the contacts API so I need to use http requests.

If any one could point me to the JSON format needed that would be great.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, what you are actually expecting?

Comment: I'm hoping someone knows the JSON format needed

Answer (score 0):

This is how we done in jquery 
`var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );`

And for javascript Json format is 


`{"employees":[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}`


Visit this for how to parse it on javascript 
http://www.w3schools.com/json/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_parse